# Passing a JSON file as environment variable in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, gcloud, google-cloud-run

Im trying to pass a secret into a Cloud Run run command. The secret is a json file. I want to pass it in as an environment variable.

It works great in docker using:

```
docker run -it -e "SECRET_ENV=$(<path/secretFile.json)" -p 8080:8080 my_image
```

When I use the same method on gcloud I get an error that tells me its trying to run each line of the json file:

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/account/project --update-env-vars "SECRET_JSON=$(<path/secretFile.json)"
```

cheers

Comment: I've never seen $(filename) as a way of getting the content of the file into the command line.  Ive always seen $(cat filename) ... can you double check that you are coding $(filename).   My thinking is that should try and execute all the commands in filename and the output becomes the variable replacement.

Comment: tried it with cat but same result thanks for trying :) Also it 100% works in the docker command been using it all through my dev process. Thanks for trying

Comment: Doh!! ... I just realized that the expansion started:

$(< filename) and not $(filename) as I had been misreading.  Sorry the for the confusion.   Next thing I would suggest is put your commands in a script file and run the file with "-x" and let's see if anything is reported as odd in an expansion.

Comment: when run with -x from an sh file I get: Bad syntax for dict arg:

Comment: We might need to look at what is "in" secretFile.json.   I wish there was an easy way to have live chats in StackOverflow ... I'd love to look over your shoulder as you work this :-(

Comment: it contains a JWK see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517 section 2.A. for an example plus I added two extra pairs with other info...also I much prefer pairing on problems I am one of the best rubber duckers you will ever meet

Comment: At a wild guess, you may have uncovered a parsing bug in gcloud run.  If we look at the spec of --set-env-vars we see it is --set-env-vars=[KEY=VALUE,...]

This has to parse the right hand-side of the parameter .... it could be a "key" is anything up to the first "=" and a value is anything up to the first ",".  Your input is JSON which may break such a simple story.  You might try and force quotes around the whole thing.

Comment: @Kolban that’s exactly what i did to fix docker don’t think another set of quotes will work lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Kolban for working through the issue with me.

And

Thanks to @tzovourn for suggestion on [berglas secret manager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/berglas#integrations)

It appears the GCP gcloud command is bugged and/or does not support JSON.

The solution I used in the end was to base 64 encode the json before setting it as an environment variable. Now docker and gcloud commands take the same data and format.

Comment: Of all things to not support. Besides who uses JSON for information transfer these days.

Comment: Did you try to escape the key separator (comma) in the variables list?
Otherwise, it would collide with the separator in your json, wouldn't it?
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#escaping

Answer (score 3):

Currently `gcloud run deploy` doesn't support setting environment variables through a json file. More information about environment variables on Cloud Run can be found [here.](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables)

You may want to file a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) for this improvement.

Comment: The idea was not to set environment variables through JSON but rather set environment variable to be json

Comment: You are right. Since you already found a workaround, (just to be mentioned) currently you are able to manage secrets in Google Cloud Platform with [Berglas and Cloud KMS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/berglas#integrations).